# Conda install locked when downloading packages

Tags: python, conda

I use Anaconda environment to handle Python package installation.
My previous `conda install` command was interrupted before completion.
If I launch again the command, it is now blocked when downloading packages.

Is there a way to get back to previous status when it was working ?

Answer (score 1):

Previous installation set a lock. That lock was not removed because of interruption.

To remove it and allow new installation, use the command:

```
conda clean --lock
```

Additional option documented [here](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-clean.html) may be useful depending on the case.